# Draw a grid inside a user drawn polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps, and have allowed the user to draw a polygon.

As in this example

[Polygon edit](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/poly_edit.html)

Now, I would like to create a grid within this polygon, a 10 x 10 grid would be ideal.

My first thought is to get the upper left, and lower right positions of the furthest points, and draw a grid based on these maximum points from the user drawn polygon.

Does anyone have any suggestions?   I would really like the grid to be cropped to the shape of the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Found exactly what I needed....

[Bounding box](http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/poly_containsLocation.html)